# Folder is empty while data transfer Sata Hard Drive From Laptop Into USB External Enclosure

Tags: data-transfer, hard-drive, sata

I need a little help - I am trying to take the data from hard drive to another laptop using Sata Hard Drive (2.5" Serial ATA Hard Drive Enclosure). However, it is successfully recognized as E drive but the drive says it is empty. My user account has administrator access (full control) 
I am able to see the drive as E drive
[image]
When E drive is opened, it says the folder is empty
[image] 
This is the view including the hidden files. It shows only the system data from the SATA drive but not from the old laptop
[image]
The reason of this data transfer is that my laptop faced blue screen while starting Windows. Bios is working fine, so I tried system recovery from the latest backup. However, it crushes at some point. I attempted a few times but seems like when it reads the same point.

It would be appreciate if someone could advise on this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resoled with installation of MiniTool Power Data Recovery.